# Can I pass a Knockout ObservableArray as an argument to ASP.NET MVC Razor @Url.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a knockout Observable which is populated during some interaction with my page. This Observable is a comma-separated value (i.e. "a,b,c"). What I need now is to pass this as an argument to @Url.Action. See below:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Benefits", "Employee", new { ids = "a,b,c" })';" />
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the click binding.

```
<button data-bind="click: function () { myFunction('@Url.Action("Benefits", "Employee")'); }">
    Click me
</button>

//then in your view model:
self.myFunction = function (actionURL) {
        window.location.href = (actionURL + '?ids=' + this.ids());
    };
```

or just the attribute binding directly on a link

```
<a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("Benefits", "Employee")?ids=' + ids() }">
    Click
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

you will need to build your url as a query string manualy

suppose `ids = ko.observable('a,b,c');`
then you'll build your url

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='@(Url.Action("Benefits", "Employee"))' + '?ids=' + $data.ids()" />
```

that will generate a url like `http://localhost:5248/Employee/Benefits?ids=a,b,c`

or try this

```
<button data-bind="click: function() { window.location.href='@(Url.Action("Benefits", "Employee"))' + '?ids=' + ids() }">
    Click me
</button>
```

<kbd>[JSFiddler DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abbasmhd/9eq59y5b/)</kbd>

Comment: I tried this, but I couldn't access the ids() - I've created a test Observable ids - but the link wouldn't even go to the location when clicked.

Comment: the ids() must be in the same scope did you try it with `$data.ids()` or `$parent.ids()` or `$root.ids()` try putting more codes please

Comment: Hi Moes, the ids() i've added as sample is in top most so based on your code, i've changed it to $root.ids(). Also tried $root.ids but still no luck.

Comment: try to bind to a click event `<button data-bind="click: function() { window.location.href='@(Url.Action("Benefits", "Employee"))' + '?ids=' + ids() }">Click me</button>` instead check the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could set the url ahead of time with a piece you replace with the actual values, it's kinda hacky, but since the MVC code is executed on the server, any MVC code would require at least a round-trip to the server to reload something.

```
urls = {
  EmployeeBenefits: '@Url.Action("Benefits", "Employee", new {ids="==ids=="})'
};
window.location.href = urls.EmployeeBenefits.replace('==ids==', "a,b,c");
```

I thought about writing an MVC action that would return javascript creating a `Url` object with the site's routes that could be used just like this but started using other ways before I got around to it.